# Assign Superclass or Interface to Subclass

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, web, lodash

I have following Setup:

```
class Dog extends Animal{}

class Animal{}
```

So basic Inheritance setup. Now I have a different class containing all Animals

```
class Farm{
     animals: Animal[];
}
```

Now at one point in the Application I need to iterate over the array, and once I find a Dog I want to assign it to a variable:

```
_.forEach(farm.animals, (animal:Animal)=>{
    if(animal instanceof Dog){
        this.dog = animal;
    }
}
```

But this gives me two errors. First the instanceof doesn't work, it says right handed side of argument is null.

And the second error is, that type Animal is not assignable to type Dog. The same happens, when I declare Animal as an Interface.

Comment: It works just fine (see link in next comment) if I make reasonable changes to the example code (putting the classes in the correct order, for instance, adding the missing `);` on the `_.forEach` call [though I changed it to the native `forEach`]). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, with the full necessary code in the question (but ideally *also* a link to that code in the TypeScript playground showing the errors).

Comment: [No errors in the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Animal%7B%20%7D%0Aclass%20Dog%20extends%20Animal%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Farm%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20animals%3A%20Animal%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20farm%3A%20Farm%20%3D%20new%20Farm()%3B%0A%0Afarm.animals.forEach((animal%3A%20Animal)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(animal%20instanceof%20Dog)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.dog%20%3D%20animal%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%3B)

Comment: But why does in my project, the Typescript Compiler say it's not assignable?

Answer (score 1):

The `instanceof` error must be some typo, `instanceof` is fine there.

The reason you can't assign `this.dog = animal;` is that you need a cast (oddly, though, I can't get the TypeScript playground to show me that error):

```
this.dog = <Dog>animal;
```

or

```
this.dog = animal as Dog;
```